# I am unable to create bucket on S3 from EC2,also unable to access/upload files into S3 bucket from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When I am trying to access S3 service from EC2 , getting Access Denied errors for different operations like create bucket, list bucket, list objects etc. I have not changed the unix user password. Even with the root user, I am unable to access the S3 service.

1] Command - aws s3 ls

> Error : An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

2] Command - aws s3 ls htcdsb-dev

> Error : An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Above errors are getting for normal unix user. For the root user below errors are getting generated.

1] Command - aws s3 ls

> Error : An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The authorization header is malformed; the authorization component "Credential=AWSAccessKeyId=A******************Q/20171122/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" is malformed

(I have purposely put asterisk(*) here to hide my access key). Except S3, I am able to access other services like IAM and AWS Glue.

I am unable to understand why the issue is occurring. Also I am unable to understand the link the between the Unix user and the AWS S3 operations.

I have created IAM role, also run AWS configure and Reboot EC2 instance but also having same issue.

IAM Role:

```
 HT_EC2_User
```

Content of AWS config file:

```
 cat .aws/config
 [default]
 region = us-east-1
 output = None
```

Comment: Do you ( your IAM User) have access to S3 that would be my first question ?

Comment: To access AWS service, you need AWS user's credentials. To specify AWS credentials, run `aws configure` (these are saved separately per unix user). (Also, that one AWS user may not have permissions to access the specific bucket(s))

Comment: Did you check right IAM policies are attached to AWS user? Do S3 bucket have any custom policies?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you please verify which AWS CLI version you are running (latest is aws-cli/1.12.0) and if required upgrade the CLI version?

Comment: Can you list out the policies attached to the IAM role

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your user and root user has different credentials configured. Can you run aws configure while logged in as the user (not superuser/root) and configure the CLI with access keys?
The malformed request could happen for several reasons, could you verify the content of .aws/config file?

Answer (score 0):

Access from EC2 to S3 is controlled by your IAM role that you assign to your EC2. Make sure that the corresponding IAM role has proper permissions to access the S3 bucket

Following is a sample permission snippet that you can add to your EC2 IAM Role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyS3BucketName/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyS3BucketName"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not really...permanent access keys can be used while an IAM role is attached to an instance and the instance profile comes last in the order while looking for credentials.

Comment: Agreed. But when you execute from EC2 instance you avoid using the access keys due to security reasons. You can use them when running from your local machines

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of and totally understat :) In this case OP did not mention that EC2 instance is using IAM role. So we can suggest for best practice use IAM role with instances but cannot conclude that it is due the permission issue for the instance profile.